# Why am I getting parse error on myFunction

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, parse-error

In the following code, I'm getting parse error on input `myFunction':

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do  
    input <- readFile inputFile writeFile outputFile (function input)
main = mainWith myFunction  
 where mainWith function = do         
        args <- getArgs          
        case args of            
            [input,output] -> interactWith function input output         
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
        -- replace "id" with the name of our function below       
        myFunction = id
```

Comment: Once you fix your error with `myFunction`, you will run into an error in `interactWith` because you can't end a do block with a bind. I'd suggest trying to compile your code more frequently.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I just noticed that as well and included the presumed fix in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myFunction = id` needs to line up with the other thing defined in the `where` clause.

```
main = mainWith myFunction  
 where mainWith function = do         
     ^  args <- getArgs          
     |  case args of            
     |      [input,output] -> interactWith function input output         
     |      _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
     | -- replace "id" with the name of our function below       
     | myFunction = id 
     | ^
     | |
     | here
     |
     not here
```

The same code with more indentation to make it clear:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do  
    input <- readFile inputFile 
    -- I assume a line break belongs here 
    writeFile outputFile (function input)
main = mainWith myFunction  
    where mainWith function = do         
              args <- getArgs          
              case args of            
                  [input,output] -> interactWith function input output         
                  _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
          -- replace "id" with the name of our function below       
          myFunction = id
```

Comment: Check my updated code, did what you said, still getting parse error.

Comment: @AliToto Now it's aligned with `args` instead. You may want to use more than one space for indentation.

Comment: `myFunction` is not part of the `do` block, which is what you are saying by lining it up with `args`.

Answer (score 0):

In haskell it is bad practice to do this:

```
where a = x
  b = y
```

This can lead to errors because it isn't lined up the same, so please make a CRNL after the where:

```
where
  a = x
  b = y
```